# HTML Auto email

Tags: php, html, email

What I am trying to do is creating a WIFI landing page where a person has to enter their email address into a box and then when clicked on 'Connect' the email address gets send to another email address so that a person is able to see what email address has been sent to them.

I think I found some code that creates a button and then sends an automatic email to the address entered, but what I am looking for is to create a textbox instead of a button.

The code already has a message line that is preset that you put into the box but I would like that part to send the email and not a preset message.

My code:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to A" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_a" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_a']))
{

$to      = 'name@ourcompany.com'; //can receive notification

$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" value="email" />
<button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['email']))
{

$to      = 'name@ourcompany.com'; //can receive notification

$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $_POST['email'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Furthermore, I would advise against using the build in mail() function and use a proper mail system instead. I'm checking if an email address was put in, but I am not checking if this email address is valid server-side. You could use `regex` (regular expressions) for this.

Comment: is it possible instead of having a separate button link it to this one (Connect)   http://prntscr.com/606qsc

Comment: Use `type='email`. Although it's only client side verification and can very easily be bypassed by someone who knows who, it still gives SOME sort of verification and is HTML5.

Comment: @Kilyosen That should be possible, although I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. And good suggestion BeatAlex, I've edited my answer.